# Label view on Apple Mail for OSX

Tags: macos, mail.app, email, gmail, imap

I'm using Apple Mail on OSX (Mavericks).
Since I'm accustomed to use Gmail webmail, which shows labels behind each email, I'm looking for a way to show labels (see for instance picture below) in a similar way on Apple Mail.

Is it possible (I assume some plugin may exist)?
If not, are there other mail clients supporting this labels functionality (i.e. Mail for OSX Yosemite)?

[image: Gmail label sample]

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at MailTags from http://indev.ca/MailTags.html - it'll show Gmail Labels in a separate column.

Answer (score 1):

Google uses Labels instead of folders, so in Apple's mail the messages with a given label will appear in a folder with that given labels name (assuming the `Show in IMAP` option is selected in Gmail's Labels setting for any given label).

If this doesn't work for you you may want to try out http://mailplaneapp.com for your gmail/os x needs.

Comment: Maybe the question is not clear: my purpose is to show labels next to each email, as in the picture.